# sql server "top 1" limitation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
select @MyVariable = SomeField from SomeTable <...>
```

If I run it moving out the @MyVariable -

```
select SomeField from SomeTable <...>
```

it does the same job and everything is ok.

Now I want to add top 1 limitation to the query, so that it will look like this

```
select top 1 SomeField from SomeTable <...>
```

Works good.

And at last, I want to add this top 1 to the initial query which sets MyVariable, and it does NOT work:

```
select @MyVariable = top 1 SomeField from SomeTable <...>
```

I get this error message -

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'top'.

Is there a way to make it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `top 1` with `@MyVariable = SomeField` as below:

```
select top 1  
       @MyVariable = SomeField 
from SomeTable <...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select top 1 @MyVariable =SomeField from SomeTable <...>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1  
   @MyVariable = SomeField 
FROM SomeTable <...>
```